# Can I disable the NSFW filter on Know Your Meme?

Tags: know-your-meme

Is it possible to disable the NSFW filter on Know Your Meme?

Any time I browse an image gallery, any potentially NSFW image is replaced by a generic thumbnail. I'd rather just have an option to view image thumbnails directly from the gallery page.